# Multiple lines of tab in Avalon Dock

Tags: wpf, avalondock

I'm using AvalonDock 2.0 as a tab control manager, however i have not come across a way to allow multiple lines of tabs (when needed), or a way to show that there are hidden tabs in the background.

Can the multiple lines of tab be accomplished through a template or style? or am i missing out on some basic properties that i didn't know?

Comment: Ever work this one out?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The answer can be found at the Xceed forum here: https://xceed.com/forums/topic/display-multiple-lines-of-tabs-in-avalondock-dockmanager/

The idea is to override the template of `LayoutDocumentPaneControl` and provide an alternative implementation, then assign this new template to the `DockingManager` via its `DocumentPaneControlStyle` property.

Comment: Updated link as OP link removed: http://forums.xceed.com/forums/topic/display-multiple-lines-of-tabs-in-avalondock-dockmanager/